# Dynamic Column Name for DBFunction in EF Core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF Core and am trying to use some super code written by Pawel Gerr that allows EF Core 3 to pass the 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER' parameter to SQL Server. Here is his blog:

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/row_number-support-in-2-1/

and the code:

https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore

His examples looks like this:

```
DbContext.OrderItems.Select(o => new 
  { 
     RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(EF.Functions.OrderBy(o.ProductId))
  })
```

What I'd like to do is have a dynamic column name like this:

```
string columnName = "o.ProductId";
DbContext.OrderItems.Select(o => new 
 { 
         RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(EF.Functions.OrderBy(columnName))
  })
```

I have tried combinations of things to do this, such as:

```
string columnName = "ProductId";
var type = typeof(T);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "o");
var property = type.GetProperty(columnName);
var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
DbContext.OrderItems.Select(o => new 
 { 
         RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(EF.Functions.OrderBy(propertyAccess))
  })
```

and

```
string columnName = "ProductId";
var type = typeof(T);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "o");
var property  = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, columnName);
DbContext.OrderItems.Select(o => new 
 { 
         RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(EF.Functions.OrderBy(property))
  })
```

However, when I evaluate the query by calling .ToList(), it throws an exception:

```
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This method is for use with Entity Framework Core only and has no in-memory implementation.
   at Thinktecture.RelationalDbFunctionsExtensions.OrderBy[T](DbFunctions _, T column)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.GetValue(Expression expression, String& parameterName)
```

It seems that because this an EF.DbFunctions extension that the stuff that works with standard link doesn't apply.

I've spent several long days trying to solve this with no luck. I've tried stepping through EF Core 3 source code, reading the source of the ThinkTecture module and everything else I can think of. I'm stumped.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,

Chris